# Freeswitch doesn't send Notify to SIP.JS for PRESENCE?

Tags: sip, voip, freeswitch

I'm trying to implement the presence in SIP.JS, i have subscribed to the presence event from the SIP.JS, and Sending Publish packets to Freeswitch from Jitsi, when i debug the packets, I found that freeswitch receives the Publish packets but he doesn't send the notify, and i tried using Linphone and Jitsi, PRESENCE works great, but with SIPJS it doesn't work.

SIPJS:

```
        sip.userAgent.on('registered', function () {

             //Subscribes to the presence information of alice@example.com
             sip.subscription = sip.userAgent.subscribe('1001@192.168.1.26', 'presence');

             // Once subscribed, receive notifications and print out the presence information
             sip.subscription.on('notify', function (notification) {
                   console.log(notification.request.body);
             });
        });
```

SIPJS Subscribe Packet: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/9JTy4HzR)

Here is the Freeswitch receives publish packet: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/4j3K19eA)

Comment: Were you using TLS/WSS when this happened? I'm having a similar problem, but only when using wss endpoints.